# Mysql event log (monitoring)

Tags: mysql, events

I have events every night in my MYSQL, and I don't really sure what is going on because it's still running in the morning even if I set it earlier than the other event.

The question is, 
how can I check the history or the log of the ran events,
which one is locked at night or which one is ran on not ran?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable slow query log in MySQL server so as to log in the slow queries in a file or MySQL table. Follow theses steps:

1. Check if slow query log is enabled for your MySQL server or not. Execute these query on the MySQL server.

   `mysql> show global variables like "%slow_query_log%";
   +---------------------+----------------------------------+
   | Variable_name       | Value                            |
   +---------------------+----------------------------------+
   | slow_query_log      | OFF                              |
   | slow_query_log_file | /var/lib/mysql/siddhant-slow.log |
   +---------------------+----------------------------------+
   2 rows in set (0.00 sec)`
2. If slow query log is not enabled, enable it like this.(or you can enable it in my.cnf or my.ini MySQL configuration file)

   `mysql> set global slow_query_log="ON";
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)`
3. Also check the long query running time i.e. the time taken by the query to be considered as a slow query. The queries taking more time than this value would be logged in the slow query log.

   `mysql> show global variables like "%long_query%";
   +-----------------+-----------+
   | Variable_name   | Value     |
   +-----------------+-----------+
   | long_query_time | 10.000000 |
   +-----------------+-----------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)`
4. Set this value to your requirement as follows.(here i am setting it to two seconds)

   `mysql> set global long_query_time=2;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

Now the slow queries will be logged in the slow query log file path as earlier returned by the query. I requirements are such that I need to monitor MySQL in real-time, you can have a look at this commercial GUI [MySQL- Monitoring Tool](http://goo.gl/eBpv57). It analyzes the slow query log in real time.

Answer (score 2):

this line will help you:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events;
```

Comment: I was looking for this query. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA good for you, good luck!!:))